# sharing audio input on Android

Tags: android, audio

I am doing some preparation research for an Android phone app that would involve voice search or speech recognition while the user is simultaneously engaged in a phone call. I'm finding that when I am in the middle of a call and attempt to invoke voice search or a similar action that would take input from the microphone I get an "audio error" message. Does the phone app take exclusive control over the microphone input of the phone such that other apps cannot get access to audio input?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the direct question, Yes. The phone app takes full exclusive control over the microphone input. This is the same with all apps that use the microphone. Only one app can have access to the microphone at a time. HOWEVER, in hope for your app, you *can* access the voice uplink stream, which is the same thing (it is what is spoken into the mic and uploaded to the service towers), plus it won't interfere with the call at all. You can do it like this:

`MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);`

You will have to add the permissions to record to the Manifest and such, but that's about it for that. Luckily the speech recognition stuff is all built in, so you should be able to find out how to do that fairly easily by just poking around a bit on here or Googleing it. Unfortunately, I myself don't have anything to offer you in that field however. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions. If a call is in progress and then I attempt to record with the VOICE_UPLINK parameter it fails. Logcat shows; 01-11 11:27:07.710: ERROR/AudioHardwareMot(1007): AudioMgr Error:AudioStreamInMot::openFd() failed: call connected
01-11 11:27:07.710: ERROR/AudioRecord(1007): Could not get audio input for record source 2
"Source 2" is the uplink. So this implies that, at least on my phone, you can't access anything coming from the mic when a call is happening.

Comment: that's weird...since that's what it's built to do, but I can't say it surprises me. On the motorola android phones, you can access the uplink (usually) but the motorola hardware doesn't allow you to access the downlink. Just yet another thing Android "supports" but is limited by hardware. :(
OH! you do have the try/catch block in place right?

Comment: Motorola XT720 I suspect? Good old Motorola software has broken the recording input when in IN_CALL_MODE

Comment: Can anyone help me on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339328/android-audiorecord-with-channel-in-stereo-read-raw-audio-buffer-resulted-in-mix